# Converting date format from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a date coming from database as **Oct 10 2013 12:00AM**

I want to convert it as 10/10/2013 like mm/dd/yy.

Comment: I suggest you convert it server side

Comment: http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/ this artical may be helpful for this scenario

Answer (score 4):

Use the [javascript date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

```
<script>
  var date = new Date('2013-04-01T19:45:11.000Z');
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  document.write(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
</script>
```

Comment: Rolled back to original answer as posted by its author.  If the code is wrong, vote accordingly and/or leave a comment.

Comment: `var month = date.getMonth() + 1;`  ;-)

Comment: The functions are case sensitive! `date()` should be `Date()`...

Answer (score 1):

Do use Server side code behind as follows:

```
 DateTime matchDay = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2013 12:15:15 AM");
 String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", matchDay); ; //10/10/2013
```

For Client side use :

If you are already using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) in your project, then you can use the built-in datepicker method for formatting your date object:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(2013, 10 - 1, 10));
```